# Making a new Command Line App in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to follow the tutorial here for printed OCR: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/java#OCR

I'm new to Azure and am not sure where to create a new Command Line App, as indicated by the first step. Can somebody please point me to where this option is in the Azure portal?

Thanks!

Comment: That is meant to be done in your IDE. Eclipse, intellij, etc

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!